# can we use common javax.annotation's in my servlet class

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

Can I use java common Annotation like `javax.annotation.Resource`, `javax.annotation.PreDestroy`, `javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed` in a `Servlet` class?

Comment: explane with more detail and with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, nothing stops you from doing so. You can use that (well, pretty much every other) annotation in any class you want. Of course if the annotation can be applied on that type of Java element (method, field, class). The annotations themselves do not bring any logic or magic in your code. Check [the source](https://github.com/javaee/javax.annotation/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Resource.java) yourself: you'll see that most of them are nothing but data holders.

Annotations are nothing without *processors*. The processing can occur at *compile time* or in a *runtime*.

Compile time annotation processing can change the source code (simplifying things here) before it is compiled. It can introduce extra behavior, (like null checks) or generate methods (like [Lombok's `@Getter` / `@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter). Compile time annotation are usually removed after processing, they are not present on a runtime.

The annotations you've asked about are different kind - runtime annotations. Obviously, resource injection or role checks cannot be done at compile time. So, they need a processor to take effect too, but that processor must be present on a class-path of a running app. Usually, such processors are provided by an *environment* you run your application in. In your case, these are Java EE annotation and they require Java EE compatible *application server* to work. I.e. the magic will happen only if you run your class inside a configured application server, like Glassfish or WebSpere. If you run you application in Tomcat or Jetty (they are *web servers*) - the annotation won't work, they will be "omitted" because no processors exist to process them.

Comment: Thank you for Explaining about Annotations in brief